# Regex for multiple matches of IP addresses

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have a string:

```
unit 3 {
    arp-options {
        aging-timer 5;
    }
    family inet4 {
        address 2.33.1.2/255.255.255.0;
        address 2.33.2.2/255.255.255.0;
        address 2.33.3.2/255.255.255.0;
        address 2.33.4.2/255.255.255.0;
    }
}
```

I want to extract the IPV4 addresses ONLY under the `family inet4` section. I can use the regex `\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}` for IP addresses but how to get all the IP addresses in one shot?

Comment: Do you want to extract also the subnet mask `255.255.255.0`  ?  Or just the ip part ?

Comment: Subnet mask also

Answer (score 2):

I would extract the `family inet4` section and then use `re.findall`:

```py
inp = """unit 3 {
    arp-options {
        aging-timer 5;
    }
    family inet4 {
        address 2.33.1.2/255.255.255.0;
        address 2.33.2.2/255.255.255.0;
        address 2.33.3.2/255.255.255.0;
        address 2.33.4.2/255.255.255.0;
    }
}"""

inet = re.findall(r'\bfamily inet4 \{\s+(.*?)\s+\}', inp, flags=re.DOTALL)
ip_addresses = re.findall(r'\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b', inet[0])
print(ip_addresses)
```

This prints:

```
['2.33.1.2', '255.255.255.0', '2.33.2.2', '255.255.255.0',
 '2.33.3.2', '255.255.255.0', '2.33.4.2', '255.255.255.0']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can if you use PyPi regex module:

```py
import regex

text = """unit 3 {
    arp-options {
        aging-timer 5;
    }
    family inet4 {
        address 2.33.1.2/255.255.255.0;
        address 2.33.2.2/255.255.255.0;
        address 2.33.3.2/255.255.255.0;
        address 2.33.4.2/255.255.255.0;
    }
}"""

matches = [x.captures(1) for x in regex.finditer(r"family inet4\s*{(?:\s*address\s+([\d./]+);)*\s*}", text)]
print([x for l in matches for x in l])
## => ['2.33.1.2/255.255.255.0', '2.33.2.2/255.255.255.0', '2.33.3.2/255.255.255.0', '2.33.4.2/255.255.255.0']
```

See an [online Python demo](https://tio.run/##jZDBjsIgFEX3fMULK9ARx2I30xg/pO2isbSStEDgmWBMv72DHZ24cCEJkFwO7@Zed8WzNXKe9eisR/CqV5EQVBHhAJTSi9EIEm4E0mq821iH2prwUBa116bfoB6Vh7xY5Gk5u2bUwxW0Ubh/5dvWqxAgE1KKnci2WZ6L5/4u3nPZh5z8kNu/5yYypdCEjA2eziqkDsooTo3DS/rKdhw66yGmSH9NiU6bVqPyzNPXtFVY3djxJ10P0yqsWVm1YluvecFX6WGiX3CvmdfEeW2QlXEZPtyHP@3/3Yaaz/Mv).

The `family inet4\s*{(?:\s*address\s+([\d./]+);)*\s*}` regex matches

- `family inet4` - a string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace
- `{` - a `{` char
- `(?:\s*address\s+([\d./]+);)*` - zero or more occurrences of

  - `\s*address\s+` - zero or more whitespaces, `address` word, one or more whitespaces
  - `([\d./]+)` - **Group 1**: one or more digits, `.`, or `/` chars
  - `;` - a `;` char
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `}` - a `}` char.

With a standard `re` in Python, you can still use a single `family inet4\s*{([^{}]*)}` regex and some more post-processing to get the same:

```py
import re
text = "STRING_HERE"
m = re.search(r"family inet4\s*{([^{}]*)}", text)
if m:
    res = [x.strip().split()[-1].strip(';') for x in m.group(1).strip().splitlines()]
    print(res)
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/Nsxj59). Here, `family inet4\s*{([^{}]*)}` matches `family inet4`, zero or more whitespaces, `{`, and then captures any zero or more chars into Group 1, and then matches a `}`.

Then, all whitespaces are stripped from the match, the match text is split into lines, and each line is processed with `x.strip().split()[-1].strip(';')`: 1) stipping whitespace first, then splitting with whitespace and getting the last item (the IP here), and then stipping the `;` from the value.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following.

```
##importing re library of python here.
import re
##Creating variable val which has OP's shown value here.
val="""unit 3 {
    arp-options {
        aging-timer 5;
    }
    family inet4 {
        address 2.33.1.2/255.255.255.0;
        address 2.33.2.2/255.255.255.0;
        address 2.33.3.2/255.255.255.0;
        address 2.33.4.2/255.255.255.0;
    }
}"""
##Creating val1 which will get all values from family inet4 to till last }.
val1=re.findall(r"(family inet4 {\n(?:.*;\n){1,}\s+})",val,re.MULTILINE)
##Creating regex2 here with .compile which will exactly match IP addresses which are just before / here.
regex2=re.compile(r"(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})/(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})")
##Using findall on val2 value to get all IP addresses here.
regex2.findall(str(val1))
[('2.33.1.2', '255.255.255.0'), ('2.33.2.2', '255.255.255.0'), ('2.33.3.2', '255.255.255.0'), ('2.33.4.2', '255.255.255.0')]
```

Comment: `regex2.findall(str(val2))` This will raise a `NameError`. You probably meant `regex2.findall(str(val1))`? Also, your output has an extra `'2.33.4.2'` address at the end of it.

Comment: @Axe319, Thank you I have edited `val2` in it, let me fix that double IP thing here, thank you cheers.

Comment: @Axe319, I have fixed the code now, thank you.